# Is it kosher to splice wiring in the "can" portion of recessed LED lighting?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I've recently installed some 4" recessed fixtures (IC rated if it makes any difference) that had an incompatible plug for the lights I bought.  The cans came with a two-pin orange colored plastic connector/harness, and the lights (Cree branded) came with an Edison style screw in connector.  In order to make this work, I bought a female edison-style screw-in adapter (with a rubber shroud), cut off the orange connector on the cans, and used wire nuts to splice the female screw-in adapter into the can's wiring  (see photo).  The photo makes this apparatus look huge but it fits very easily into the cavity above the light.  Can I get thoughts on whether this passes muster with the electrical code?  Or is it a bad idea for any other reason?

[image]

Comment: What voltage???

Comment: So the transformer is in that male edison connector?

Comment: Chris, that's my understanding -  Cree put all of their circuitry in this model in that male Edison adapter (perhaps to limit the height of the actual light portion).  This is an admittedly stupid, roundabout way of fixing my mistake of buying a light with an Edison bulb connector. Hopefully it's code-compliant stupid, if there is such a thing.  Thanks for your time my friend.

Comment: Well, it's not Kosher unless it's blessed by a Rabbi.  But I think it's safe.  Just make sure those connections are good and solid.  I find splicing wires of different gauges to be difficult at times.   Were your connections outside the can, then we'd have a clear code violation.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore 120VAC

Answer (score 1):

You are in code as long as there is enough room for every thing and you do not have to modify the can. The can would be considered the junction box. Also you need to make sure you have installed the correct cans for the type of insulation that is around the can, you should be okay. ie If the can is installed in an area that is surrounded by insulation the can must be rated for it, or a shroud must be built as an air gap for those that are not.

[image: Shroud]

Without the correct can, if the can has a thermal overload, the thermal overload will over heat and shut down power to the light and become a nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason that you would not be able to disconnect the Cree device (white connector) from the black socket.  Then cut and strip the red and black wires about a 1/2 inch each.

Make sure that power is turned off, remove the wire nuts which will free the black socket.
Twist each wire from the Cree fixture a wire that had a wire nut on it. That should free up space in the can. You perhaps will need someone to hold the fixture while you do the work doas to prevent dropping it.